# Display search form and navbar menu item in one row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display search form and navbar menu items in one row whereas right now it is showing in two rows.

HTML:

```
<title>This is test</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script> 
<script src="js/modern-business.js"></script> 
<!-- Navigation -->
<header id="header">
    <div class="top-bar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
        <form action="" class="search-form">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label for="search" class="sr-only">Search</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="search">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                   <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Create Account</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Cart</a></li>
               </ul>

                   </div>
                </div>

        </div><!--/.container-->
    </div><!--/.top-bar-->
```

CSS:

```
 #header .search{
 display: inline-block;
 }

 .navbar>.container .navbar-brand{
   margin-left: 0;
   }

  .top-bar {
   padding: 10px 0;
   background: #191919;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
   line-height: 28px;
   }

 .search i {
  color: #fff;
  }

 input.search-form{
 background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
 width: 60px;
  padding: 0 10px;
 color: #FFF;
 -webkit-transition: all 400ms;
-moz-transition: all 400ms;
-ms-transition: all 400ms;
-o-transition: all 400ms;
 transition: all 400ms;
}


 .search-form .form-group {
  float: right !important;
  transition: all 0.35s, border-radius 0s;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
  border-radius: 25px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   }
  .search-form .form-group input.form-control {
   padding-right: 20px;
   border: 0 none;
   background: transparent;
   box-shadow: none;
   display:block;
   }
  .search-form .form-group input.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   display: none;
   }
  .search-form .form-group input.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
   /* Firefox 18- */
   display: none;
   }
  .search-form .form-group input.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
 /* Firefox 19+ */
  display: none;
  }
  .search-form .form-group input.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
   display: none;
    }
    .search-form .form-group:hover,
   .search-form .form-group.hover {
    width: 100%;
     border-radius: 4px 25px 25px 4px;
     }
    .search-form .form-group span.form-control-feedback {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
     right: -2px;
     z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    width: 34px;
     height: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
     text-align: center;
     color: #3596e0;
    left: initial;
     font-size: 14px;
```

How can i show both navbar menu items and animated search form in one row instead of two rows.

This is jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yomozon/pLvp7ru0/5/)

Thanks for help.

Comment: Sorry, could you make your question more clear? Cuz now your demo seems to be in 4 rows not just 2...do you mean one column?

Comment: Please try searching. Variations on this question have been posted under the [css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tag a ridiculous number of times to day.

Comment: yes sorry in one column i want to show search form right next to navbar menu items not on top of navbar menu items

Answer (score 1):

I would post this as a comment query, but lack the rep.

Does changing the line

```
.search-form .form-group {
  float: right !important;
}
```

to

```css
.search-form .form-group {
  float: left !important;
}
```

as seen in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pLvp7ru0/6/ almost solve your problem? It seems slightly too quick, so I might well be misunderstanding the question.

Comment: this helped me but still it is not aligned vertically center

Comment: @user1120133 Do you want the search field to be a menu item identical in appearance to the others, or do you still want it to be animated as it is at the moment?

Comment: i want search form to be animated on hover as it is at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Create Account</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Cart</a></li>
              <li id="your_search"> [put your form here]  </li> 
               </ul>
```

Then, in your CSS, you can specify #your_search to 'right'